# how to stop moving background-image position

Tags: javascript

I've background image and by using small javascript code, it moves from right to left.

HTML code

```
<div id="clouds_image"></div>
```

Javascript code

```
var g=0;
var speed=30;
function rollClouds() {
document.getElementById('clouds_image').style.backgroundPosition=g+'px 0';
g--;
scroller=setTimeout(function(){rollClouds()},speed);
}
window.addEventListener?
window.addEventListener('load',rollClouds,false):
window.attachEvent('onload',rollClouds);
```

But i've noticed that, with time my PC CPU memory usage increased ! causing overload on my pc and if i disabled that javascript code, it back to normal.

**My question**

so i think i need to modify this javascript code that it **not** keep working forever, i mean, i want to make it to repeat that action only 5 times then stop , maybe i need to define value of `g` but i'm not good in javascript so any help ~ Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a variable to count how many times that function was executed, and use setInterval instead of setTimeout: See example

http://jsfiddle.net/EQDjx/206/  (my counter start from 100 and goes down to 0)

for a more nice effect i recomand you to use jquery. See animate function
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
var g = 1000;
var speed=300;
var counter = 100;
function rollClouds() {
document.getElementById('clouds_image').style.backgroundPosition=g+'px 0';
g--;
if (counter < 1) clearInterval(interval);
}
interval = setInterval(function(){rollClouds()}, speed)
```

Comment: Thanks, But it still working forever and looks like it not counting down every execute of the function it keep considering 100 > 1 so working forever and no dropping in counting.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner solution might be to use jQuery to move the background:

```
function moveClouds() {
    $("#clouds_image").css({left:"-2000px"});
    $("#clouds_image").animate({left:"2000px"},10000);
}
```

Then you might set an interval to trigger it every x milliseconds.

```
setInterval(moveClouds,10000)
```

JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/qXpVX/

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i wonder if i would like to use the javascript code in my question rather than jQuery.

Comment: You can use your code. But really, you don't want to. jQuery is designed as a free tool to make your life easier, and as a seasoned web developer, I can say 100% it's worth your time to learn.

Comment: I try to avoid 70KB loading as i only need that effect so if my website needs other effects then indeed will just jQuery :)

Comment: 32KB, according to their site. And with caching, it's only downloaded once, but I understand where you're coming from there.